# Can't modify some contents conditionally

Tags: string, vba, excel

I've written a script in vba to manipulate the content of some cells conditionally. However, I'm getting stuck solving this. The way I've tried below is a faulty approach but this is the best I could do.

> Condition: If there is a cell contains `{` followed by `any nummber` and again followed by a `+` then it should be placed as it is in the next column. Otherwise, the `{` and `}` sign should be kicked out from that content and get placed to it's adjacent column.

Content are in `Range("A1:A4")`. Refined content should be placed to it's adjacent column in corresponding cells.

I tried:

```
Sub GetRefinedContent()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("A1:A4")
        If Left(cel, 3) = "{" Then ' a faulty approach definitely
            cel(1, 2) = Replace(Replace(cel, "{", ""), "}", "")
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

The above macro doesn't do anything cause the conditions are never met.

Contents are:

```
a^{5}b^{7} 
a^{5+x}b^{7+y}
a^{3}b^{5} 
a^{3+x}b^{5+y}
```

Expected output:

```
a^5b^7 
a^{5+x}b^{7+y}
a^3b^5 
a^{3+x}b^{5+y}
```

Comment: For your code you would need to use `mid(cel,3,1)`because `Left`will give all chars from the beginning. But anyway even wtih this change your code would not work as you do not check if there is a + sign.

Comment: @Storax raises a good point below. What would be the expected output in that use case?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this. It should solve the problem. Check out [this link](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/visual-basic/language-reference/operators/like-operator#parts) to learn about `Like` operator.

```
Sub GetRightPart()
    Dim cel As Range

    For Each cel In Range("A1:A4")
        If Not cel Like "*{?+*" Then
            cel(1, 2) = Replace(Replace(cel, "{", ""), "}", "")
        Else:
            cel(1, 2) = cel
        End If
    Next cel
End Sub
```

Answer (score 1):

Using regex

```
Option Explicit
Public Sub test()
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Dim loopRange As Range, rng As Range, ws As Worksheet
    Set ws = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1")
    With ws
        Set loopRange = .Range("A1:A" & .Cells(.Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row)
    End With
    For Each rng In loopRange
        rng.Offset(, 1) = GetString(rng.Value)
    Next rng
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
End Sub
Public Function GetString(ByVal inputString As String) As String
    Dim regex As Object
    Set regex = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    With regex
        .Global = True
        .MultiLine = True
        .IgnoreCase = False
        .Pattern = "\{\d\+"
    End With

    If Not regex.test(inputString) Then
        GetString = Replace(Replace$(inputString, "{", vbNullString), "}", vbNullString)
    Else
        GetString = inputString
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: What about `a^{521s+x}b^{7+y}`? Though I think this is a question for the TO.

Comment: The instructions say keep the string as is if the pattern of {x+ is found where x is any number though good point.